# How to pick which UV map will be exported with model?

Tags: texturing, uv, export

**Short explanation of the issue:**

1. I've got 2 UV Maps, one for texturing and the other for the baking, optimised for the engine.
2. I have successfully baked the textures of my model using both UV Maps.
3. Now I want to export the model with the UV Map that matches the baked texture map but no matter what I do, the wrong map gets exported.
4. The baked texture doesn't show up on the model correctly because it's using the UV Map used for texturing and not the one for baking.

**What I've tried so far:**

1. Setting the one I want to export to Visible in Object Data Properties.
2. Changing the names so that the one I want to export is called "UVMap".
3. Deleting the UV map used to texturing.

And here's the thing, solution 3. works but I don't want to be deleting all those maps on my model, taking it into the engine to test and then not be able to come back to blender and fix any mistakes.

Is there anyone who can advise/assist on this issue? I'm sorry if this is an obvious one, I'm a relatively new blender user moving from Maya.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you simply duplicate your object, duplicate the material, and remove the UV map in the duplicated version?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the reply! Technically that works but I am hoping there's a more elegant solution that doesn't involve deleting things :) I will do this for now, thanks!

Comment: I guess in your case you completely depend on how the game engine works so you have no other choice